# Avoid Duplicate Records - HashSet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, arraylist, hashset

I'm trying to multiple objetcs of DTO into an `ArrayList` through a `for` Loop. Once all objects are added, for avoiding duplicates I'm converting `ArrayList` into `HashSet` to avoid duplicate records.

Code Snippet -

```
....

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

for( .... ){ 
  Class factory = DTO.getClass();
  Object bean = factory.newInstance();
  list.add(bean);
}

return new ArrayList(new HashSet(list));
```

But the returned `ArrayList` has duplicates, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Even if two instances of your DTO contain exactly the same values, they will be considered different by the HashSet. To be considered equal, `dto1.equals(dto2)` (and `dto2.equals(dto1)`) must return true. So you must override the `Object.equals()` method in your DTO in order to specify when two DTO instances are equal. And when you override `equals()`, you must also override `hashCode()`. Two equal objects **must** have the same hashCode.

Read the documentation of those two methods, and use your IDE to generate those two methods if you don't know how to implement them.

Answer (score 3):

you need to override the equals and hashcode methods that are inherited from Object. Java does not known that the two objects are equal unless you tell it what to compare. The Hashset class will call the equals method of your object to do the comparison

Lets take the example of car, which has two fields; type and color. Two objects will be considered equal if they are the same type and the same color.

If we don't override the equals method we will get false when we have two objects that are the same

```
public class Car {

private String type;
private String color;

public Car(String type, String color) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
    this.color = color;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car1 = new Car("Suv","Green");
    Car car2 = new Car("Suv","Green");
    System.out.println(car1.equals(car2)); //false
}
```

}

in this example we will tell java how we want it to compare the objects by overriding the equals method

```
private String type;
private String color;

public Car(String type, String color) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
    this.color = color;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
    if (this.getClass() == obj.getClass()){
        Car other =(Car)obj;
        if(this.color.equals(other.color) && this.type.equals(other.type)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car1 = new Car("Suv","Green");
    Car car2 = new Car("Suv","Green");
    System.out.println(car1.equals(car2)); //true
}
```

running this example you will get true.

If you test out a hashset with the object without the overridden equals you will have both classes in their because java thinks they are different objects since the equals returns false. Test it out with the overridden method an you will only have one

Also any time you override equals you should override hashCode as well. Use your favorite IDE to help you out with these.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You should use a class of the interface `Set` directly. This one avoid by definition duplicates

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

```
Set list = new HashSet();

for( .... ){ 
    Class factory = DTO.getClass();
    Object bean = factory.newInstance();
    list.add(bean);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend HashSet instead of TreeSet as its much faster (Constant time vs log-time in most of the basic operations) and also there is no requirement to preserve the order of elements.

Comment: sure, just used TreeSets before so used this as a habit. Changed the code

Comment: Using the set directly instead of using an intermediate list won't make the OP's problem disappear.